# Firefox textarea padding bug?

Tags: html, css, firefox, textarea, padding

## Most browsers

All the browsers render textarea padding like chrome: (pic below)
[image: chrome textarea padding done right]

## Firefox inconsistency

But firefox renders it like this for some reason?? (pic below... see how the padding cuts off the words when they overflow)
[image: firefox textarea padding weirdness]

If anyone has some information on why this happens / a good fix please share! Thanks!

Oh, and here's the code from screenshots: [codepen](http://codepen.io/johnchinjew/pen/Vapzyj)

```
textarea {
  display: block;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  resize: none;

  height: 230px;
  width: 500px;
  background: #ddd;

  padding: 50px; /* here's where it get's weird */
  margin: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Probably because textarea are somewhat replaced elements. You can try a contenteditable div.

Comment: But aren't <textarea>s better with text input formatting and don't they have  more semantic value?

Comment: Yes, you are right. But as a workaround, it works: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WwpZwP

Comment: woops didnt mean to post... :P

Comment: thanks, ill try it out Oriol